# Mysql random row update/select : what about precomputed random value?

Tags: mysql, random

I use a mysql DB. I have some process to update or select rows on the biggest table of this DB. It is not so big now, but it will be. I know getting random rows could be complex or time consuming on big table on Mysql.
I think about to add a column to store a random number (0.1, 0.2,... 0.9) whe' create a new records. When I need to get a random records, I will generate  a random number and select all the rows with the same number.

Is it a good idea to handle random in mysql?
I could regenerate the random column  sometimes to get some more randomness.

Comment: I think you are looking for a hashing algorithm, not random number generator.
Think about this, and correct your question if so.

Comment: Using the ID modulo something is another interesting way tackle this pseudo-precomputed-randomness